# How can I format the Android ActionBar, including its background colors and fonts, as well as the tabs it contains?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, styles

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically manipulate the appearance of the Android ActionBar and its tabs, but this process is not straight forward when using the API. I want to change the background color and the font for the ActionBar, but I also want to make it match the background color and font for the individual tabs. Is there a simple way to do this, either in code or using styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This set of styles formats the ActionBar, including background, title and subtitle text; it also formats the tabs, including all its possible states (selected, unselected, and all the focused/pressed combinations), as well as the tab text font and size (per Android developers instruction https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/themeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabs</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/themeActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/styleActionBarTabs</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="themeActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abactionbargradient</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarSubTitleText</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/abactionbargradient</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/styleActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="styleActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="styleActionBarSubTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_sub_title_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="styleActionBarTabText"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="styleActionBarTabs"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abactionbartabs</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/abactionbartabs</item>
</style>
```

This set of styles looks especially nice when the drawables are gradients using some set of coherent color values (i.e. lavender to purple for selected and purple to lavender for unselected, changing the values to darker for pressed and lighter for focused).